# Foreach loop with mixed stdClass objects and arrays

Tags: php, object, foreach, stdclass

Here I have an output from a website using Soap

```
stdClass Object 
( 
  [page] => 0 
  [items] => 3 
  [total] => 3 
  [saleItems] => stdClass Object 
  (
    [saleItem] => Array 
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object 
      ( 
        [reviewState] => open 
        [trackingDate] => 2011-11-03T01:06:43.547+01:00 
        [modifiedDate] => 2011-11-03T01:06:43.677+01:00 
        [clickDate] => 2011-10-30T22:57:57.383+01:00 
        [adspace] => stdClass Object 
        (
          [_] => Beslist.nl [id] => 1437603
        ) 
        [admedium] => stdClass Object 
        (
          [_] => 001. Program logo
          [id] => 535098
        ) 
        [program] => stdClass Object 
        (
          [_] => Zavvi NL
          [id] => 8991
        ) 
        [clickId] => 1565847253976339456 
        [clickInId] => 0 
        [amount] => 40.45 
        [commission] => 2.83 
        [currency] => EUR 
        [gpps] => stdClass Object 
        (
          [gpp] => Array 
          (
            [0] => stdClass Object 
            (
              [_] => shoplink 
              [id] => zpar0 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
        [trackingCategory] => stdClass Object 
        (
          [_] => Default
          [id] => 45181
        ) 
        [id] => 46a4f84a-ba9a-45b3-af86-da5f3ec29648 
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I want to have the data (with a foreach loop) from program, commission and gpp->_. I can get the data from program and commission like this:

```
foreach ($sales->saleItems->saleItem as $sale) {
  $programma    = $sale->program->_;
  $commissie    = $sale->commission;
}
```

Works like a charm. However I can't get the data from the `gpp->_` (want to have shoplink as result). I currently have:

```
foreach ($sales->saleItems->saleItem->gpps->gpp as $tracking) {
  echo $tracking->_;
}
```

I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object". I've tried lots if variations and can't get it to work. Think I'm really close. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
   foreach ($sales->saleItems->saleItem as $sale) {
        foreach($sale->gpps->gpp as $tracking) {
            echo $tracking->_;
    }
```

As `saleItem` is an array, you won't be able to use chaining on it.